# SQLAlchemy how can i only retrieve one related entry in index query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I try to write my query to produce the following outcome:

```
@api.get("/market-symbols/", response_model=List[schemas.MarketSymbol])
def show_market_symbols(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    threshold_time = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds=10)
    
    query = select(models.MarketSymbol)
    result = db.execute(query).scalars().all()
    
    # Filter the related records to keep only those older than 10 seconds
    for market_symbol in result:
        market_symbol.market_symbol_price = [
            price for price in reversed(market_symbol.market_symbol_price)
            if price.timestamp <= threshold_time
        ][:1]  # Limit to one record
    
    return result
```

Currently i need to iterate over the results and their relations after getting the Date from the Database.

Those are my Models:

```
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Float, ForeignKey, BigInteger
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column, relationship, Mapped
from sqlalchemy.types import Date
from database import Base

class MarketSymbol(Base):
    __tablename__ = "market_symbol"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, index=True)
    market_symbol_price: Mapped[List["MarketSymbolPrice"]] = relationship('MarketSymbolPrice', back_populates="market_symbol")
    symbol = Column(String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    currency_base = Column(String(20), nullable=True)
    currency_quote = Column(String(20), nullable=True)
    type = Column(String(50), nullable=True)

    def toJson(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "market_symbol_price": self.market_symbol_price,
            "symbol": self.symbol,
            "currency_base": self.currency_base,
            "currency_quote": self.currency_quote,
            "type": self.type,
        }

class MarketSymbolPrice(Base):
    __tablename__ = "market_symbol_price"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, index=True)
    market_symbol_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("market_symbol.id"))
    market_symbol: Mapped["MarketSymbol"] = relationship('MarketSymbol', back_populates="market_symbol_price")
    timestamp = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    price = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    bid = Column(Float, nullable=True)
    ask = Column(Float, nullable=True)

    def toJson(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "market_symbol_id": self.market_symbol_id,
            "market_symbol": self.market_symbol,
            "timestamp": self.timestamp,
            "price": self.price,
            "bid": self.bid,
            "ask": self.ask,
        }
```

Those are my schemas:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
import datetime

class MarketSymbol(BaseModel):
    id: int
    market_symbol_price: Optional[list]
    symbol: str
    currency_base: Optional[str] = None
    currency_quote: Optional[str] = None
    type: Optional[str] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class MarketSymbolPrice(BaseModel):
    id: int
    timestamp: datetime.datetime
    price: float
    bid: Optional[float] = None
    ask: Optional[float] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

I would like to query the database to only retrieve one related Model. The Model should also be older than 10 seconds. How can this be achieved maybe using subqueries? I was not able to find anything online. Thank you for your response and thoughts!

For example if i have a MarketSymbol with multiple MarketSymbolPrice relations i would get the following Output from the Query:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "market_symbol_price": [
            {
                "price": 136.37,
                "id": 26526,
                "ask": null,
                "market_symbol_id": 2,
                "timestamp": "2023-08-21T11:35:31",
                "bid": null
            },
            {
                "price": 136.37,
                "id": 26526,
                "ask": null,
                "market_symbol_id": 2,
                "timestamp": "2023-08-21T11:35:33",
                "bid": null
            }
        ],
        "symbol": "NASDAQ-TMUS",
        "currency_base": null,
        "currency_quote": null,
        "type": null
    }
]
```

but i want to only have the latest MarketSymbolPrice in the relation:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "market_symbol_price": [
            {
                "price": 136.37,
                "id": 26526,
                "ask": null,
                "market_symbol_id": 2,
                "timestamp": "2023-08-21T11:35:33",
                "bid": null
            }
        ],
        "symbol": "NASDAQ-TMUS",
        "currency_base": null,
        "currency_quote": null,
        "type": null
    }
]
```

Comment: sadly not - if i set the limit in the subquery to one i still receive all market_symbol_price in the response. do you maybe have another way of getting this to work?